# Write $f(x) = \int_{-2}^{x}t|t-1|\,dt$ without the sign of integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is my attempt:

$\displaystyle \int_{-2}^{x}t|t-1|dt$

=$\begin{cases} \displaystyle\int_{-2}^{x}t^2-tdt, \; t \ge 1 \\\displaystyle \int_{-2}^{x}-t^2+tdt, \; t <1\end{cases}$

=$\begin{cases} \displaystyle\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{(-2)^3}{3}+\dfrac{(-2)^2}{2}=\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{14}{3}, \; x \ge 1 \\\displaystyle -\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}--\dfrac{(-2)^3}{3}-\dfrac{(-2)^2}{2}=-\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{14}{3}, \; x <1\end{cases}$

However, the solution in my list is:

=$\begin{cases} \displaystyle\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{13}{3}, \; x \ge 1 \\\displaystyle -\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{14}{3}, \; x <1\end{cases}$

Is my attempt wrong or is the solution in the list wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x>1$, I get
$$\int_{-2}^xt|t-1|\,dt=\int_{-2}^1t(1-t)\,dt+\int_1^xt(t-1)\,dt.$$